# How to get only the latest revision of a document

Tags: java, couchdb, ektorp

I am new to CouchDb/ektorp. According to the ektorp documentation you can generate couchdb views through an annotation like this:

```
@View( name = "avg_sofa_size", map = "function(doc) {...}", reduce = "function(doc) {...}")
```

Is there a way to get only the latest revison of each doc, not by id but another attribute? <-- not java specific

And if possible only get only one doc not by id but another attributefrom that view? <-- ektorp/java

Thakns

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get only the latest revison of each doc?

Couch always gives you the latest revision, unless you ask for a particular revision:

```
GET http://localhost:5984/mydb/doc-123
```

Returns latest revision of doc-123

```
GET http://localhost:5984/mydb/doc-123?rev=946B7D1C
```

Returns a specific revision of doc-123.  (Revisions are kept by couch only for conflict resolution.  They are removed during compaction and are not replicated, so you shouldn't necessarily count on them being there)

> And if possible only get only one doc by id from that view

If you just want to get a document by id, there is no need to use a view.  Looks like you want to do something like this with ektorp:

```
Sofa sofa = db.get(Sofa.class, id, rev);
```

Where `Sofa` is a java class which extends `CouchDbDocument`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I know that it can be done like that. But in both cases I would need the knowledge about id or rev. So if I don't have those and I query by something like a unique name wit an CouchDBSupportRepository I'll always get a list of revisions for the doc with that name.

Comment: I don't know what CouchDBSupportRepository does, but when you query a view, you're going to get back a list of documents, not a list of revisions.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the other answer, you will always get the doc with the latest revision if you don't explicit specify the revision.

```
Sofa sofa = db.get(Sofa.class, id);
```